# "git branch" command is slow from Git Bash on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I only have one branch `main` but when I execute the `git branch` command, it took about 30 seconds to complete. Other commands like `git status` does not have this performance issue. What are some of the things that I can check here?

Git version is 2.36.0 running on Windows 10.

UPDATE:

- Also opening up Git Bash is slow (around 20 seconds). I tried the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47542488/1160753. Git Bash opened  up quickly after that change but the subsequent action of opening up the Git Bash is back to take approximately 20 seconds.
- When Git Bash is executed under "Run As Administrator", `git branch` completed quickly. BUT that is not every single time. There are times that the same command takes 30 seconds to complete (this is without any additional branch)

Comment: Have you tried an another system? How "old" is the repository ?

Comment: Does the delay also happen when you do the command twice in a row? How many objects does `git count-object -v` report?

Comment: @Schwenk the repository is 2 days old.

@j6t The delay does not happen when I execute the command twice in a row. But if I wait let's say for 30 seconds before executing the same command, then `git status` takes a long time again to finish.

`git count-objects -v` reports 21 objects

Comment: Is this on Windows, and the PC is registered in a domain, but the domain server is unreachable?

Comment: @j6t This is on Windows and yes the PC is registered in a domain. Once I connect to the domain through VPN, the `git branch` command completed quickly. Does this mean that I have to be connected to the domain network all the time?

Comment: Well, only if you use Git all the time. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Tl;dr

On Windows, when the PC is in a domain, make sure that the domain controller is reachable.

## Details

The shell and command line tools that are distributed with Git for Windows are derived from the [MSYS2 project](https://www.msys2.org/), which is based on a variant of the Cygwin library. As part of the program startup routine, the library does several name lookups. When the system is registered in a domain, this lookup goes to the domain controller. In the case when the domain controller is not reachable, the lookup waits for time-outs. This causes the delays.

The results of the lookup is cached by Windows. Therefore for a short time, subsequent startups do not have to wait for the time-outs. But ultimately the cache expires and the next program invocation has to wait again.

The Git program, `git.exe`, is *not* based on the Cygwin library and does not need the name lookup. It can run without delay. However, many Git commands spawn a pager, typically `less`, which *does* suffer from the delay; therefore, it appears as if Git itself would be delayed. (Not that it matters; the user experience is bad either way.)

On top of that there are many other cases where Git runs a command line tool: hooks, textconv filters, ssh, etc. All of them can suffer from the delay.

EDIT: I am currently testing the following change.
Do ***NOT*** make this change to your system unless you know exactly what the security implications are.

I used `mkpasswd` and `mkgroup` to cache the current domain information locally:

```
mkpasswd >> /etc/passwd
mkgroup >> /etc/group
```

Then I removed duplicates from the files. (But `/etc/group` did not exist before these commands.)

This idea was taken from the [Cygwin FAQ](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.startup-slow).

Comment: Is there a setting to disable the name lookup?

Comment: See the edit. The BIG caveat is that I do not know the security consequences.

Comment: Thanks. That FAQ definitely worth a read.