# Git commands (that use less.exe) takes too long on Windows

Tags: git, domaincontroller

The following git commands take way too long to execute on my Windows PC:

- `git config --list`
- `git branch`
- `git push`
- `git pull`

Sometimes, Git throws the following error:

```
PS D:\SB\Code\Sharepoint_Integration> git branch
      0 [main] less (5036) C:\Users\gautamj\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\less.exe: *** fatal error - add_item ("\??\C:\Users\gautamj\AppData\Local\Programs\Git", "/", ...) failed, errno 1
Stack trace:
Frame         Function      Args
0007FFFFCD30  00021006116E (000210290E7A, 000210272B51, 000000008000, 0007FFFF8B30) msys-2.0.dll+0x2116E
End of stack trace
Loaded modules:
000100400000 less.exe
0005D1C20000 msys-pcre2-8-0.dll
7FFB3C1D0000 advapi32.dll
7FFB3D6A0000 msvcrt.dll
7FFB3C280000 sechost.dll
7FFB3C050000 RPCRT4.dll
7FFB3A390000 CRYPTBASE.DLL
7FFB3ACD0000 bcryptPrimitives.dll
```

However, commands like `git add` and `git commit` executes almost instantly, like it's supposed to. From the error, it looks like `less.exe` is the main reason. From my research, this occurs in PCs registered to a domain (and the problem being the domain controller), which mine happens to be. This issue only happens when I am connected to wifi. But, how do I resolve it?

EDIT: I do not face the problem when running git commands with the `--no-pager` flag. However, if I use the less.exe directly (say `echo test | /path/to/less.exe`) the problem persists.

Comment: First try to exclude `less`: do commands like `git --no-pager config --list` and `git --no-pager branch` run quick enough? Second, exclude `git`: does command `echo test | less.exe` run fast?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["git branch" command is slow from Git Bash on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436188/git-branch-command-is-slow-from-git-bash-on-windows)

Comment: @phd thanks for those commands, i've edited the question, the test proves that the issue is indeed with less.exe

Comment: @j6t the issue is similar, but there is no clear solution, especially because of the security implications

Comment: One solution is to ensure that the domain controller is reachable. Then there are no security implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug in Git for Windows v2.41.0.windows.1

Simply upgrading to Git for Windows v2.42.0.windows.2 solved the problem.

> Some Git commands (those producing paged output, for example) experienced a significant slow-down under certain circumstances, when running on a machine joined to a domain controller, which has been fixed.

- Issue: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4459
- PR: https://github.com/git-for-windows/MSYS2-packages/pull/124